# EC2 Instance CPU utilization

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud

We know that aws don't have permission to access the customer EC2 instance, my question is if they can't access customer EC2 machine then how they are calculating CPU utilization and display in graph.

Is it showing main **host machine** CPU utilization ?

Answer (score 2):

AWS runs EC2 servers on a Xen Hypervisor which gives them visibility into the CPU utilization of your instances.

Comment: To extend on this... Amazon CloudWatch metrics for EC2 instances include only CPU, Network and Disk access since these are visible to the Hypervisor. For metrics such as Memory Utilization and free memory, a [script](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/mon-scripts.html) must be run on the instance that queries the Operating System and sends the results to CloudWatch.